# Value of the $# variable

Tags: variable

```
set 10 20 30 40 50
```

> Enter the value of the variable `$#`:

I understand that the variables `$1=10` `$2=20` and so on

Answer (score 2):

In POSIX shells, the value of special built-in variable `$#` corresponds to the number of positional parameters set. Ex.:

> Set `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` and set "`$#`" to 3:

```
set c a b
```

From [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html)

Answer (score -1):

$# is the number of arguments
$* are the arguments
$@ are the arguments

Look at this

```
#!/bin/sh
set 1 2 3 4
echo "we had $# args"
echo Arguments are  $@ using echo '$@'
echo Arguments are  $* using echo '$*'
```